# calculate memory address from IDA to use with Frida

Tags: ida, memory, dynamic-analysis, address, frida

I saw an interesting value in IDA at address `0xf8766`; I want to view the value at that address.

I debug an Android application with Frida, how can I put this address in Frida to watch this value?

I know that I need to use `Memory.readByteArray(ptr(0xXXXXX), 8)`, but what will be the correct address?

Should I read `/proc/PID/maps` to see the first address and then add this address to the address that I want to see? The first address is `anon:dalvik-main space (region space)`